# Common scale for List of ContourPlots

Tags: plotting

Given a list of `ContourPlot`:

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[Sin[x] + Sin[y], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}];
cp2 = ContourPlot[2*(Sin[x] + Sin[y]), {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {y, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}];
cpList = {cp1,cp2}
```

How can I make the contours (and color steps) for all elements of `cpList` the same, whilst being able to specify the `List` of contour magnitudes manually (e.g. `Range[-2, 2, 0.5]`)?

---

`Contours->Range[-4, 4, 0.5]` (better than above) does part of the work, but the color-scales arent equal:
[image: no equal color scale]

Comment: [`Contours`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Contours.html)? E.g. `Contours -> Range[-2, 2, 0.5]`

Comment: @corey979 That's part of it, but the color-scale is not equal.

Comment: @DPF You can use `ColorFunction` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the color scaling equal you have to supply your own `ColorFunction` and turn off `ColorFunctionScaling`. Add for instance the options

```
ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-3, 3}]] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

to both plots and you get something like

[image]

where I added plot legends via `PlotLegends -> Automatic` for reference

Comment: That's a good way to do it. The only thing I'd like to have in addition to your solution is equal Legends for all Plots

Comment: you mean a common legend shared by both plots?

Comment: I mean each plot has its own legend, but showing the same number-range and colorfunction.

Comment: by the way: is there a possibility, to `Rescale` the existing `ColorFunction`s?

Comment: @DPF you can create your own custom `BarLegend` for instance `BarLegend[{{Red, Blue}, {-3, 3}}, Range[-3, 3, 0.5]]` and use it inside each plot